# Set toplevel for Python package

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this folder structure:
[image]

okay, i have below code in my main application (`main.py`)

```
from Modules.Core import Core1
print Core1.HouseNumber()
```

and below code in `Core1.py`:

```
from ..Engine import Engine1
def HouseNumber():
    house = Engine1.BadLuck()
    return house
```

also this code in `Engine1.py`:

```
def BadLuck():
    return 13
```

this work perfectly without any problem, alright.
NOW, here the interesting part, i have below code in `Widget1.py`

```
def door():
    return 'black'
```

and this code in `Core2.py`:

```
from ...Widgets import Widget1
def DoorColor():
    door = Widget1.door()
    return door
```

and if i change my `main.py` to:

```
from Modules.Core import Core1, Core2
print Core1.HouseNumber()
print Core2.DoorColor()
```

I get this error: `Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package`.

okay, now if i take `Main.py` out of `ProjectX` in Drive `D` and change the `main.py` codes to this:

```
from ProjectX.Modules.Core import Core1, Core2
print Core1.HouseNumber()
print Core2.DoorColor()
```

it work perfectly.
okay, I understand if i `from Modules.Core import Core1, Core2` means `Modules` is my top-level but not `ProjectX`even i included `__init__.py`to the folder structure.

Here my question:

> Is there any way i can define toplevel folder in `main.py` without moving the main file around?

**Note1:** also there is solution by adding full path like: `from ProjectX.Modules.Core import Core1` and `from ProjectX.Widgets import Widget1`, but it's not a best solution,cause i have to do `sys.path.append()` and i think there is a smart way.

**Note1:** also i have done adding `__all__` inside `__init__.py` of `ProjectX`:

```
__all__ = ['Modules','Widgets']
import Modules
import Widgets
```

I didn't get any result.
I do include above example [here](https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0BwoMn9VKDw-tb0RCZFk1YVBISzg&export=download) for download/study.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need relative import in your `CoreX.py` files.

Simply change `Core2.py`:

```
-from ...Widgets import Widget1
+from Widgets import Widget1
```

Note: You can refactor your imports to remove all relative import.

```
diff --git a/Modules/Core/Core1.py b/Modules/Core/Core1.py
index a0650fc..c6109e6 100644
--- a/Modules/Core/Core1.py
+++ b/Modules/Core/Core1.py
@@ -1,4 +1,5 @@
-from ..Engine import Engine1
+from Modules.Engine import Engine1
+
 def HouseNumber():
     house = Engine1.BadLuck()
-     return house 
\ No newline at end of file
+    return house 
diff --git a/Modules/Core/Core2.py b/Modules/Core/Core2.py
index 2638734..b131d1f 100644
--- a/Modules/Core/Core2.py
+++ b/Modules/Core/Core2.py
@@ -1,4 +1,6 @@
-from ...Widgets import Widget1
+from Widgets import Widget1
+
 def DoorColor():
        door = Widget1.door()
-       return door
\ No newline at end of file
+       return door
```

Comment: wow!! that work! i can't believe i made such simple mistake!! thanks, so it work because my main application run from there right? also what if my main application is inside `Widgets` for example, how can i add folders that are parent of main application's folder?

Comment: Yes, it works because your application start in projectX folder. To add external folders, you need to add them to your path (same as external module are loaded)

Comment: `import sys; sys.path.insert(0, '/my/path/python/packages')` I think we are done here, please accept the answer so others can see it as solved.

Comment: i see... so there is no any function in python to set toplevel. either start from where i run the application or add the path to sys.path, alright thanks for the answer.